# How can I make this query more set based?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression, recursive-query

This is my first post here, so please let me know if I've not given everything needed.

I have been struggling to rewrite a process that has recently been causing me and my server significant performance issues.

The overall task is to identify where a customer has had to contact us back within +2 hours to +28 days of their previous contact. Currently this is being completed via the use of a cursor for all the contacts we received yesterday. This equates to approximately 50k contacts per day.

I am aware that this can be done through a cursor or a recursive CTE, but I feel like both options are bad. I am looking for another method to do the same job.

Below is a sample extract and the outcome i am expecting to see.

```
INSERT INTO SourceData ([CUSTOMER_KEY], [CONTACT_REFERENCE], [CONTACT_DATETIME], [EXPECTED_RESULT])
VALUES ('1', '100', '01/04/2020 09:00', 'Original Contact'),
       ('2', '101', '01/04/2020 10:00', 'Original Contact'),
       ('3', '102', '01/04/2020 11:00', 'Original Contact'),
       ('1', '103', '01/04/2020 12:00', 'Repeat of Contact Reference 100'),
       ('1', '104', '01/04/2020 13:00', 'Not Repeat - within 2 hours of previous contact'),
       ('1', '50' , '01/04/2020 14:00', 'Repeat of Contact Reference 103'),
       ('2', '105', '01/04/2020 14:00', 'Repeat of Contact Reference 101'),
       ('1', '106', '01/04/2020 15:00', 'Repeat of Contact Reference 104'),
       ('1', '200', '27/04/2020 12:00', 'Repeat of Contact Reference 106');
```

The process i currently follow is below.  I am happy to update my post to provide code, but I don't think this will be too useful given that I am looking for other solutions.

1. Identify the current latest repeat of every customer.  This was here to reduce the requirement on the full data table. If there was a repeat contact within the time frame already, then I can just assign it straight to that. This data is loaded into a new temp table: TempTable_Repeats_By_Customer.
2. Add all the contacts from yesterday to a temp table: TempTable_Yesterdays_Contacts
3. Open the cursor to start processing each Contact (from step 2) in order of Contact_DateTime (Ascending). At the same time i use TempTable_Repeats_By_Customer to identify if the customer has already had a repeat - and if this was within the eligible time frame.
4. If an existing repeat exists, retrieve the details from my existing reporting table and load a new row in.
5. If no existing repeat exists, check the full data table for other contacts received during the eligible period.
6. If there are more contacts from the same customer on a single day, I then go back and update TempTable_Repeats_By_Customer with the new details.
7. Either go to the next item in the cursor, or close and deallocate it.

Any help you all can give is much appreciated.

Comment: What you want can absolutely be done without a cursor. If you're looking for actual code, you'll need to provide table schemas, sample data, and a mock up of your expected result. See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips. If you're looking to have a conversation about strategy, this is the wrong forum for that. See [Where is the SQL Server Community Networking Online?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/07/where-is-the-sql-server-community-networking-online/) for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am overlooking something, but I think you should be able to do this using the [LAG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#SourceData', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #SourceData;

CREATE TABLE #SourceData
(
    [CUSTOMER_KEY] VARCHAR(10)
  , [CONTACT_REFERENCE] VARCHAR(10)
  , [CONTACT_DATETIME] DATETIME
  , [EXPECTED_RESULT] VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO #SourceData
(
    [CUSTOMER_KEY]
  , [CONTACT_REFERENCE]
  , [CONTACT_DATETIME]
  , [EXPECTED_RESULT]
)
VALUES
('1', '100', '04/01/2020 09:00', 'Original Contact')
, ('2', '101', '04/01/2020 10:00', 'Original Contact')
, ('3', '102', '04/01/2020 11:00', 'Original Contact')
, ('1', '103', '04/01/2020 12:00', 'Repeat of Contact Reference 100')
, ('1', '104', '04/01/2020 13:00', 'Not Repeat - within 2 hours of previous contact')
, ('2', '105', '04/01/2020 14:00', 'Repeat of Contact Reference 101')
, ('1', '106', '04/01/2020 15:00', 'Repeat of Contact Reference 103')
, ('1', '200', '04/27/2020 12:00', 'Repeat of Contact Reference 106');

SELECT x.CUSTOMER_KEY
     , x.CONTACT_REFERENCE
     , x.CONTACT_DATETIME
     , x.EXPECTED_RESULT
     , x.[Minutes Difference]
FROM   (
           SELECT
                CUSTOMER_KEY
              , CONTACT_REFERENCE
              , CONTACT_DATETIME
              , EXPECTED_RESULT
              , DATEDIFF(
                            MINUTE
                          , LAG(CONTACT_DATETIME) OVER 
                            (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_KEY ORDER BY CONTACT_DATETIME)
                          , CONTACT_DATETIME
                        ) AS [Minutes Difference]
           FROM #SourceData
       ) x
WHERE  x.[Minutes Difference] > 60
       AND x.[Minutes Difference] < 40320 -- this is the number of minutes in 28 days
```

Here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=3f7df389314e8433b381c80aa755cf16).

Comment: How many minutes in 2 hours? Is that before or after coffee/tea/beverage of choice?

Comment: You aren't kidding. My coffee is still brewing. I'll review my answer later when I have more time.

Comment: Thanks @Isaac , I like the idea of your solution. If i was to have another contact inside the 2 hours, it should still assign the repeat contact to the earlier of the two. This can be shown by adding the following to the Source Table.
('1', '50' , '04/01/2020 14:00', 'Not repeat - within 2 hours of previous contact') 

I would still expect contact 106 to be a repeat of 104. Because its only looking at the previous row, not the previous eligible row.  Can this be bypassed?

Comment: @MatthewM, I cannot quite understand what is a repeat and what is not. I am going to have to bow out for now.

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses a recursive CTE to process the contacts in date/time order for each customer. Like Isaac's answer it calculates a delta time in minutes which may or may not be adequate resolution for your purposes.

**NB**: [`DateDiff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) "returns the count (as a signed integer value) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed". If you specify a datepart of `day` you'll get the number of midnights crossed, not the number of 24-hour periods. For example, Monday @ 23:00 to Wednesday @ 01:00 is 26 hours or two midnights, while Tuesday @ 01:00 to Wednesday @ 03:00 is still 26 hours, but only one midnight.

```
declare @SourceData as Table ( Customer_Key Int, Contact_Reference Int, Contact_DateTime DateTime, Expected_Result VarChar(50) );

INSERT INTO @SourceData ([CUSTOMER_KEY], [CONTACT_REFERENCE], [CONTACT_DATETIME], [EXPECTED_RESULT])
VALUES ('1', '100', '2020-04-01 09:00', 'Original Contact'),
       ('2', '101', '2020-04-01 10:00', 'Original Contact'),
       ('3', '102', '2020-04-01 11:00', 'Original Contact'),
       ('1', '103', '2020-04-01 12:00', 'Repeat of Contact Reference 100'),
       ('1', '104', '2020-04-01 13:00', 'Not Repeat - within 2 hours of previous contact'),
       ('2', '105', '2020-04-01 14:00', 'Repeat of Contact Reference 101'),
       ('1', '106', '2020-04-01 15:00', 'Repeat of Contact Reference 103'),
       ('1', '200', '2020-04-27 12:00', 'Repeat of Contact Reference 106');

with
  ContactsByCustomer as (
    -- Add a row number to simplify processing the contacts for each customer in   Contact_DateTime   order.
    select Customer_Key, Contact_Reference, Contact_DateTime, Expected_Result,
      Row_Number() over ( partition by Customer_Key order by Contact_DateTime ) as RN
      from @SourceData ),
  ProcessedContacts as (
    -- Process the contacts in date/time order for each customer.
    -- Start with the first contact for each customer ...
    select Customer_Key, Contact_Reference, Contact_DateTime, Expected_Result, RN,
      Cast( 'Original Contact' as VarChar(100) ) as Computed_Result,
      0 as Delta_Minutes
      from ContactsByCustomer
      where RN = 1
    union all
    -- ... and add each subsequent contact in date/time order.
    select CBC.Customer_Key, CBC.Contact_Reference, CBC.Contact_DateTime, CBC.Expected_Result, CBC.RN,
      Cast(
        case
          when PH.Delta_Minutes < 120 then
            'No Repeat - within 2 hours of previous contact'
          when 120 <= PH.Delta_Minutes and PH.Delta_Minutes <= 40320 then
            'Repeat of Contact Reference ' + Cast( PC.Contact_Reference as VarChar(10) )
          else
            'Original'
          end
        as VarChar(100) ),
      PH.Delta_Minutes
      from ProcessedContacts as PC inner join
        ContactsByCustomer as CBC on CBC.Customer_Key = PC.Customer_Key and CBC.RN = PC.RN + 1 cross apply
        -- Using   cross apply   makes it easy to use the calculated value as needed.
        ( select DateDiff( minute, PC.Contact_DateTime, CBC.Contact_DateTime ) as Delta_Minutes ) as PH
     )
  -- You can uncomment the   select   to see the intermediate results.
  -- select * from ContactsByCustomer;
  select *
    from ProcessedContacts
    order by Customer_Key, Contact_DateTime;
```

Comment: Thanks HABO, I have updated the insert statement in my original post with a case that breaks the logic you've provided. Contact Reference 50 (newly added) breaks the 2 hour chain into two periods of 60 minutes.  Instead of looking to the previous line, it should look back to the latest contact from at least 2 hours before.

Comment: @MatthewM - There seems to be something unclear about "within +2 hours to +28 days of their **previous contact**". For `50` the _previous contact_ is `104`, but that is apparently ignored because `103` is a better choice. For `106` the _previous contact_ is `50`, but you've chosen `104`. What are the rules?

Comment: Sorry - good call out.  The +2 hours limit is to remove contacts from the same telephone call. So the previous contact would be the one with the max contact date/time when the contact date/time is not within the last 2 hours of the current contact. Is that any clearer?

Comment: Nope, not clear yet. So `106` looks back and sees that `50` was only 1 hour ago. Instead of dropping it as `'Not Repeat'` it looks back another row and finds that `104` was 2 hours ago, hence it declares itself a repeat of `104`. Let's reconsider `104`. It peers back in time and finds that `103` was only 1 hour ago, so it _doesn't_ go back to `100` at 4 hours in the past, but just gives up and goes with `'Not Repeat'`. What am I missing?

Comment: You're correct - 104 has been mislabled and should be a repeat of contact 100